What made WordPress become dominance for small websites, comparing to other CMSes?
From FAQ | Publii:

[W]ithout any complicated back-end infrastructure to manage and maintain, static websites are particularly well-suited to small business websites, portfolios, personal blogs, or other sites that don't need to be updated constantly.

WordPress creates dynamics web pages, so for this type of users it has less advantage in compared with static site generators. But still, WordPress is a dominant player in the field. From various discussion like this one, it seems that the consensus is that WordPress has network effect and low-entry barrier. I think the latter one is because of it is a WYSIWYG, GUI CMS. I also notice 2 things:

Today web technologies like Git, Node, or React hasn't existed at the time WordPress was born (2003)
Dynamic web requires more resource than static web, and is better suit for large-scale sites like e-commerce platform, social media, etc. This makes hosting companies has more profit when customers buy their products to install dynamics web. Thus they have an incentive to advertise dynamic web software more. If the customers associate "building website" with "building WordPress", then they will have more profit.

But then what makes these points cannot be applied to other CMSes? I only see one plausible reason is that when it released it was the first CMS to have better UI: one-click installer, GUI admin dashboard, WYSIWYG editor, drag-and-drop page builder, etc. And from that it gained the network effect: enormous plugin and theme store, helping resource, job opportunity, etc. I think my question can be refined to this one:
What made WordPress better than other CMSes in term of UI that existed around 2003? Why couldn't they have an easy installer and better UX like WordPress?

I'd argue "better" is the wrong word to use.  Most CMSs have specific strengths and weaknesses.  In the case of WordPress, it's easier to hack something together than Drupal or Joomla, meaning you need less technical skills to get something up-and-running (albeit often with spaghetti code and exploitable plug-ins). Out-of-the-box, it remains really good for blogs, with all the blog features you need already there, plus has enough support and history to know it'll be around a long time and people will answer your technical questions. New CMSs could go under any day - they are a gamble.

I've updated the question. Can you check?

I think this question is really opinion based.  Here is mine.
Wordpress was "Good Enough", and easy enough to set up.  Many webservers - even way back then had PHP support built into them, making it easy to host.  PHP is also an easy language to "program" in as its interpreted.  This made it a lot easier to set up then something which relied on CGI's - which most mass servers did not support.
Another thing that is relevant is Wordpress's license is conducive to helping it spread - at least in the early stages - where it would be predominantly small players who wanted something free and easy (no coding) - and similarly the ease of writing modules for the framework as a write once - use everywhere helped it become all things to all people.
I also think your second contention
"Dynamic web requires more resource than static web, and is better 
suit for large-scale sites like e-commerce platform, social media, etc.
This makes hosting companies has more profit when customers buy their
products to install dynamics web. Thus they have an incentive to advertise
dynamic web software more. If the customers associate "building website"
with "building WordPress", then they will have more profit"

Lacks nuance - specifically I don't think that dynamic sites have anything to do with large scale or social media.  Indeed I don't think that hosting companies made more profit when customers buy their products to install dynamic web pages - I think this became a requirement - and PHP + MySQL was fairly common - and easy to do because it was all open source.   I just did a bit of Googling and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29 says that the LAMP stack (which is all that is needed for Wordpress) became a thing in 1998.
I think the GUI page builder was a big part of Wordpresses success - although it was hardly unique - there were a couple of Freeware editors that could be used by any software to create this kind of functionality (and indeed Wordpress relied on this from fairly early on I think - I believe it used to use TinyMCE - although it looks like TinyMCE was released after the first versions of Wordpress)
I feel so old now.   I was in the ISP industry before all of this existed.

So I take that your points are: WP's license and its infrastructure components (PHP and MySQL) are both FOSS, and it was the first one to integrate with GUI page builder. Am I correct? As for the first point, isn't that other CMSes like Joomla and Drupal are the same? As for the second point, I suppose other CMSes would soon integrate GUI page builder into their code. So why would the market share still be so disproportional since then? And why would all hosting companies only sell dynamic web pages and not static web pages?

I think wordpress was just easier then Joomla and Drupal out the box.  I could be wrong.  Also Wordpress started off as a Blogging platform, which is different to Joomla and Drupal which started off at customer management systems.  I'd be surprised if even most hosting companies only sold dynamic pages.  Static web pages are much easier from a hosting point of view.   Of-course developing static pages is a lot harder then dynamic ones - especially for non-techies.

Do you mean that because Joomla and Drupal focused on customer management systems, it has little incentive to integrate GUI page builder? If static pages are much easier to host, then what do you mean by "I think this became a requirement"?

I think that the web migrated from something for geeks to something for everyone - and "everyone" was able to use the Wordpress system to build and update their sites - while not everyone could code in PHP.   By became a requirement I mean "became a requirement of many people who wanted websites"
